# how to write a RESTful filemanger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-management

today i have direct a problem :P i just need some ideas...
how do you would write a RESTful filemanager in rails?

i want to use a files controller which does all the operations with the files.
now when i do it restful there are just some few functions:

- create (create a file/directory)
- destroy (delete a file/directory)
- index (list a directory)
- show (show properties of a file)
- edit (rename a file/directory)

now i dont know how to copy/move a file...
and when i want a user to have several instances of that filemanager, how do i manage that he can be in different directories? (have different instances of my filemanager in one session)

can anyone just give me some hints? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define **file** as a resource in rails routing. Then you have your RESTful routes. It doesn't matter for rails if you have a file- or a database-resource. The RESTful routes are the same. The unique identifier for your files could be the unique filename: "/files/file.pdf".

I would suggest you to use an abstraction to perform operations on the filesystem (like an Object-Relational Mapping for database access). I could think of [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) for example. It handles file uploads and provides basic operations like delete/destroy. Also it allows you to change you storage volume (file, gridfx, amazon s3).

I'm not sure what you mean with different instances of a filemanager. It would be possible to define a file manager for each user. For instance with [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) you can define custom storage dirs:

```
# mount uploader in user class
class User
  mount_uploader :file, UserUploader
end

# define user uploader
class UserUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
    # model = user object as the uploader
    # is mounted in the user class
    'public/uploads/#{model.id}'
  end
end
```

I hope you get an idea!

Comment: so you mean i should use files as resources? or file as resource? :P when i use it as resource, i could use the index function to get the contents of the directory with index ;)

Comment: and with different instances i meant the problem that when i just use file as resource, then i have to save the current directory in a session-variable. this would make it harder to have different instances of the manager in one session...
thanks for the tip with the custom storage dirs ;)

Comment: I meant with "file as resource" just the [resource definition](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) in rails routing. A file is basically nothing more than a resource. Can you give an example for the different instances? Are you trying to build something like a FTP-Client?